# HttpClient - Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, ssl, https, dotnet-httpclient

I've been writing some code that pulls data from an external source. Essentially first it gets a list of the events that relate to today, processes it, then gets a list of events that relate to tomorrow. Depending upon how many events there are in a given day the processing can take a number of hours. Here is the problem:

If I run `ScrapeToday()` and `ScrapeTomorrow()` immediately after one another without the processing everything is gravy. However, as in the normal program flow, if there is a large gap between the operations I catch the following error;

`The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

My first instinct is that this must be due to a bug in `HttpClient`, likely something expiring due to the long duration between requests. However as a new client is created for each request I wouldn't've thought it possible. I've done some digging around on SO and some other sites but have not been able to reach the root of the problem - any help would be appreciated!

Code below.

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<string, Calendar.Event>> ScrapeToday()
{
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        WriteLine("Requesting today's calendar...");
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(calendarTodayUrl);
        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Calendar.Event>>(json);
        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Scraper.Instance.WriteLine("Error retrieving today's calendar: " + e);
        return new Dictionary<string, Calendar.Event>();
    }
}

public static async Task<Dictionary<string, Calendar.Event>> ScrapeTomorrow()
{
    try {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        WriteLine("Requesting tomorrow's calendar...");
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(calendarTomorrowUrl);
        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Calendar.Event>>(json);
        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Scraper.Instance.WriteLine("Error retrieving tomorrow's calendar: " + e);
        return new Dictionary<string, Calendar.Event>();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Since posting I have tried making a global httpclient and using that for both requests. That also did not work.

**Edit2:** The bug is reproduceable with an elapsed time of 30 minutes between the calls.

**Edit3:** If the call is retried after the failure it always works.

Comment: i would like to see what happens if you catch the exception when calling `ScrapeTomorrow` and simply re-issue the call? This is not a solution (hence a comment) - just a further diagnostic step

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Re-issuing the call works.

Comment: Would you be able to explain why this might be?

Comment: short answer, i dont know :) I am glad it is working. perhaps you should consider an alternative rest/request library like http://restsharp.org/ which I and many others have used in preference to `HttpClient`

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue? Im getting the same using HttpClient. Thx.

Comment: @Vindberg when it catches the error I just have it try again.